# How to get raw mouse events with XI2 extension?

Tags: mouseevent, x11, xlib, raw-input, xinput

I'm using XISelectEvents for root window with `deviceid=XIAllDevices` and `mask=XI_RawMotion`, but I don't get any events. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

While looking through the header files, I noticed that there is `XI_RawMotion` and `XI_RawMotionMask`. Does the later fix your problem?